# How to input geospatial data into MS SQL Server via Python and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, geometry, sql-server, mysql-spatial

I'm trying to add a GeoJSON file into the SQL Server database. I have this following script that works fine for inputting the geospatial data into MYSQL Database, thus creating a GEOMETRY type column in the DB.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pymysql
import pymssql
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.types import UserDefinedType

class Geometry(UserDefinedType):
  def get_col_spec(self):
      return "GEOMETRY"

  def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
      return func.ST_GeomFromText(bindvalue, type_=self)

  def column_expression(self, col):
      return func.ST_AsText(col, type_=self)

geodataframe = gpd.read_file(r"my_geojson_file.geojson")

DATABASE_URL_SQLSERVER = 'mssql+pymssql://username:password@<server>.database.windows.net/database?charset=utf8'
DATABASE_URL_MYSQL = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@server/database?charset=utf8'

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL_MYSQL)

geodataframe.to_sql('my_new_geom_table', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False,dtype={'geometry':Geometry})
```

However, when I follow this same structure to add it to `sqlserver` database (I used the variable `DATABASE_URL_SQLSERVER` instead of `DATABASE_URL_MYSQL` [see code above] containing the string connection), It gives me the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\matheus.barros\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 689, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 476, in pymssql.Cursor.executemany
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 450, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1070, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1101, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1218, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1240, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_sql_command
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1879, in _mssql._substitute_params
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1856, in _mssql._quote_data
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1832, in _mssql._quote_or_flatten
ValueError: expected a simple type, a tuple or a list
```

Someone has a hint in how to overcome that?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that your `bind_expression` method does not work correctly as you need another function in MSSQL and you are not able to use `func.` here since "::" is in the function name needed in MSSQL (see also the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58668255/is-there-an-example-sqlalchemy-userdefinedtype-for-microsoft-sql-server-geograph)).

The following geometry class definition worked for me:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import sqlalchemy as sal

# custom sqlalchemy usertype to convert wkt-column to geometry type
class Geometry(sal.types.UserDefinedType):
    
    def __init__(self, srid: int = 4326):
        self.srid = srid

    def get_col_spec(self):
        return "GEOMETRY"

    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        return sal.text(f'geometry::STGeomFromText(:{bindvalue.key},{self.srid})').bindparams(bindvalue)


# connect to and write gdf to database
con = engine.connect()
gdf.to_sql(name='NEW_TABLE',
           #if_exists='append',
           index=False,
           dtype={'geom': Geometry(srid=crs_input)},
           con=con,
           schema = 'dbo')
con.close()
```

Comment: Adding this for others who stumble upon it trying to copy records from another SQL data source. To read geometry data from MSSQL to a dataframe it is possible to cast it to WKT in the select statement, e.g. `select geom.STAsText() as geom from <table_name>`. This will work without GeoPandas.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `Geometry` is not an instantiable data type in SQL server - see [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-types-overview?view=sql-server-ver15)

Regarding a solution (and sorry for the edit, I fat fingered `send`), assuming you want to use your own classes, your best bet is likely to make a class for all the relevant types - `Point`, `LineString`, etc. Also, since I'm not an expert on SQL server, I'd double check to make sure the `ST_xx` functions exist on SQL server.

You could probably make everything a `GeometryCollection` to avoid having to make a bunch of classes, but I'm sure you know this brings a menagerie of potential pitfalls when, eg, converting to WKT, performing geometric operations, and really doing anything with a sizable data set.